# Cleanup [monitors], [display] and [screen]

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

So, [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) says that it's about GNU Screen <sup>[verification needed]</sup>, but then there's [monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors) which is about "Computer monitors (i.e. screens or displays)", and there's also [display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display). Is common that people use them rather interchangeably which makes tagging hard. What should be done?

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) is about Screen, the program, which is known as GNU Screen to the younger generations. [monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors) is about peripherals that turn a digital or analog electrical signal that represents a picture into visible light. [display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) is a bit fuzzier: it's generally about the information flow from an application that wants to display something to the display hardware, including but not limited to the concept of displays in X11.

I don't see much misuse of the tags. We currently have 304 questions tagged [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen), and 36 questions [had the tag initially but no longer do](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/215917/posts-from-which-an-initial-tag-was-removed?Tag=screen). We may have missed a few, but not many by eyeballing the question list. That's an acceptable success rate.

(Note: [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) has now been renamed to [gnu-screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) to avoid the ambiguity.)